# What is the idiom to criticize someone's speech, especially when they a make a lot of repetition?

Tags: idiom-meaning

What is the idiom to describe unreasonable repetition in someone's speaking or writing? For example,if someone says, wet water or salt is salty.

Comment: It's redundant, I don't think there's an idiom for it.

Answer (score 2):

"Salty salt" is an example of tautology. That is the technical name for it.

But are you looking for a derogatory idiom, rather than a technical word?